# Oracle: Rollback only crash iteration of loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions

I need help to accomplish rollback on iteration if one or more iterations crash and to commit all others iteration if they success. If crash, it will rollback whole transaction. Think this can be done with Savepoints, but I'm not very familiar with them. This is a basic example what i try to achieve.

```
    DECLARE 
      ...
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. 10
      LOOP
        BEGIN
          -- Some DML and stored procs with DML
          INSERT INTO a .. .;
          INSERT INTO b .. .;
          INSERT INTO a .. .;
          DELETE FROM a .. .;
          UPDATE INTO c .. .;
          m_package.some_proc_with_dml;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            merror   := merror + || ', ' || + sqlerrm;
            miserror := TRUE;
        END;
      END LOOP;

      COMMIT;

      IF miserror THEN
        raise_application_error(-20000, merror);
      END IF;

    END;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can set a  `SAVEPOINT`, and then rollback to that SAVEPOINT e.g.:

```
    DECLARE 
      ...
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. 10
      LOOP
        BEGIN

        SAVEPOINT my_savepoint_name;

-- Some DML and stored procs with DML
          INSERT INTO a .. .;
          INSERT INTO b .. .;
          INSERT INTO a .. .;
          DELETE FROM a .. .;
          UPDATE INTO c .. .;
m_package.some_proc_with_dml;
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            merror   := merror + || ', ' || + sqlerrm;
            miserror := TRUE;

            ROLLBACK TO my_savepoint_name;

        END;
      END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to wrap loop statements in a nested call of separate stored procedure with [PRAGMA](http://psoug.org/reference/autonomous_tx.html) [AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/autotransaction_pragma.htm).